# automatic download with hidden anchor tag not working on firefox

Tags: angularjs, firefox, angularjs-scope

This code working fine on chrome but not in firefox. Why?

```js
 var element = angular.element('<a/>');
 element.attr({
   href: 'data:attachment/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(atob(response.payload)),
   target: '_blank',
   download: 'export.csv'
 })[0].click();
```

Answer (score 1):

Answering because I just had the same problem and stumbled upon this thread: unlike Chrome, Firefox needs you to append the new element to the DOM before you can click it. This can be achieved with `document.body.appendChild(element)` in vanilla JavaScript.